# how to access the task form of human task in jbpm spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jbpm

I have integrated the `JBPM 5.4` with `Spring Framework 3.x.x` using local service. My web application runs successfully. I've use `LocalHTWorkItemHandler` to start, execute, suspend or complete the human task.

But my problem is that how I can show the form associated with the task to user. I can do this thing using REST API by calling `/gwt-console-server/rs/form/task/{id}/render`. But how to retrieve the form and integrate it into view of the my `SpringMVC` application?

Comment: could you please post the spring integration human task example.There is no tutorial found to refer.I would be thank to you if i get such example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use what the jBPM console provides as part of the REST service, but if you want something more integrated in your own application, you could just render the task forms yourself, they are simple freemarker templates where the task data is inject into.  Take for example a look at this class (and the others in the same package):
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/5.4.0.Final/jbpm-gwt/jbpm-gwt-form/src/main/java/org/jbpm/integration/console/forms/TaskFormDispatcher.java

Answer (score 0):

I believe you use Guvnor for storing your assets (process-definition, rules, etc).By default the task's form is stored by the name "*TaskName-taskform*" in guvnor.

You can use the rest services exposed by the Guvnor and read the form's source.

I believe that is how TaskFormDispatcher ,as mentioned by Kris, gets the form source.

Ex. The source of a task named "*UpdateComments*" in package "*HR*" will be

```
 http://guvnorserver:8080/drools-guvnor/rest/packages/HR/assets/UpdateComments-taskform/source
```